# How to turn on shell hints in python?

Tags: python

Is there something like hints in python's shell? For example I type variable/class name then dot and press tab, and I have all possible attributes and methods. How can I turn this on if there is?

Comment: What has your *research* shown on this subject?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python interpreter itself does not have hints. What you want is the iPython package, which has this functionality (and much much more).

> pip install ipython

and then

> ipython